# If I place a view on top of any other (or partially) I get a ClassCast exception

Tags: android, android-layout

Title basically says it all.

I've a layout like this:

[image]

And the real code in layout is this (bgImageSliderContaine, containerTopMenu and titleContentContainer are irrelevant.):

[image]

So the actual layout order, is crashing, but if I just change the position of `containerRightOptional` it stops crashing, but obviously, its not placed where it should:

[image]

This is the error message:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.View cannot be cast to android.widget.ScrollView at project.carregarSection(productView.java:234)

And the code of that line is:

```
ScrollView contentContainer = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
```

As you can see, its totally correct, as the ID of the scrollView is the accurate.

Do you've any idea about what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving things around in the layout can sometimes cause this. Try `Project -> Clean... -> Clean all projects` first if it solves your problem.

Comment: The best part is that I thought about cleaning it after asking... Thank you so much about the tip, this totally solved the issue.

Comment: Welcome! I also encountered this long ago and it gave me a mild headache. :)